# how to create 8 regular users automated(scripted) from a CSV file in google workspace

Tags: google-workspace, google-workspace-add-ons

[Google Workspace user creation](https://github.com/aktar11087/task/blob/main/create_users.sh)

I am having trouble connecting to Google Workspace with my script in order to create users on admin.google.com. Has anyone had success creating users on Google Workspace using a bash script?

any help is highly appreciated